# Pseudo element reduces in size when elements around grow

Tags: html, css

I have the following code for a label and checkbox, which when the label content is short, looks perfect like so:

[image]

However, when the label becomes longer, the checkbox is "squashed" and the tick no longer aligns inside it, how can I use flex to create a more versatile solution?

[image]

```css
.outter-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 8px 24px 8px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.label-wrapper {
 line-height: 1.5rem;
}


.label {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 24px;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;

}

.label:before {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  flex: none;
}

.label:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 80%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.label::after {
  background-image: url("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/447/447147.png");
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter-wrapper">  
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input class="input" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2"        type="checkbox">
    <label class="label" for="checkbox2">
      <div class="label-wrapper">
        Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1
      </div>  
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know possibly `flex-wrap` may be the correct approach but not sure if it's possible considering the "checkbox" is created using `:before`?

Comment: It's because you left `flex-shrink` at the default value, so the pseudo element is _allowed_ to shrink in width below the 20px you specified. Replace `width: 20px` with `flex: 0 0 20px`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```css
.outter-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 8px 24px 8px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.label-wrapper {
 line-height: 1.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
}


.label {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 24px;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

.label:before {
  display: block;
  min-width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}

.label:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 80%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.label::after {
  background-image: url("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/447/447147.png");
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter-wrapper">  
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input class="input" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2"        type="checkbox">
    <label class="label" for="checkbox2">
      <div class="label-wrapper">
        THis world is full of creatures
      </div>  
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/LYjKWEw

**Note:** May require to use `min-height` on any parent(if required),  so that text remains within input box

Answer (score 2):

You need a `flex : none` if you want a fix width for an element that is inside a flexed container. Hope it resolve your problem.

```css
.outter-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 8px 24px 8px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.label-wrapper {
 line-height: 1.5rem;
}


.label {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 24px;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;

}

.label:before {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* a line I added*/
  flex:none;
}

.label:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 80%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.label::after {
  background-image: url("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/447/447147.png");
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter-wrapper">  
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input class="input" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2"        type="checkbox">
    <label class="label" for="checkbox2">
      <div class="label-wrapper">
        Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1Option 1
      </div>  
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this - although the issue with the "tick" is still considerably outside the checkbox, but the `flex: none` is very helpful for preventing the checkbox from shrinking!

Comment: Great, I saw that someone helped you solve this second issue.

Comment: thanks for the help in getting there, have a great day ! :)